# Transliteration support in 14.04+?

Tags: keyboard-layout, cyrillic

Ubuntu 12.04 used to have very nice transliteration support for GTK+ based apps, where right-clicking would allow you to select 'Input Methods > Cyrillic (transliteration)'. I find that much easier and nicer to use than Russian phonetic keyboards provided in 14.04 and later.

Is it possible to get transliteration back?